# IE11 saves downloaded .xlsx files corrupted in angular using blob (works locally)

Tags: node.js, angular, blob, internet-explorer-11, xlsx

When I download a .xlsx file from server, the downloaded file does not have the proper structure (stylesheet, worksheet etc.) but it is just a binary file with .xlsx extension.

**Notice:** It works perfectly on Chrome, Firefox, Edge and locally even in IE11 and I have set internet explorer's security settings to be the same for local and remote websites.

This is how the server creates the response:

```
const buffer = json2xls(values, { fields: fields });
res.end(buffer, 'binary');
```

This is how the client saves fetched data:

```
downloadFile(selectedReport) {
const blob = new Blob([selectedReport.blob()], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, `result.xlsx`);
}
```

I have tried replacing:

FileSaver.saveAs(blob, `result.xlsx`);

with:

window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, `result.xlsx`);

but the result remains the same.

**Notice:** the content of the corrupted `result.xlsx` file is the same as the `buffer` sent by the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check out your http server MIME Types ?
the one for .xlsx should be 
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Comment: You mean setting the response header contenttype to 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' ?

Comment: It turned out that, that was the problem. I set the 'Content-type' to 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.shee' and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First check your response object by consoling it, if the data type is application/xlsx or application/.xlsx then use below code.

```
    const blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/xlsx"});
    const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url)
```

When response is not 'application/xlsx' then mention what data type [image] you are getting in the console

```
const blob = new Blob([data], 
{type: "application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
    const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url)
```